# Creating a ROS msg and srv tutorial problems

Tags: ros, begginer-tutorials

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I've been stuck on this problem for the last two days and would really appreciate some help.

I'm following the ROS tutorial on msgs ans srv and every time I get to the catkin_make install part I get the following error.

`CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/genmsg/cmake/genmsg-extras.cmake:151 (message): add_service_files() directory not found: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/srv Call Stack (most recent call first): beginner_tutorials/src/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_service_files)`

One forum I looked into stated that I can just comment out add_service_files() from the CMakeLists.txt. However, when I do that I get the following error

```
 /home/user_name/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_server.cpp:2:83: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
 #include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h" //header file generated in the SRV file
                                                                                   ^
compilation terminated.
/home/user_name/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/add_two_ints_client.cpp:2:43: fatal error: beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h: No such file or directory
 #include "beginner_tutorials/AddTwoInts.h"
```

Again I appreciate any help I can receive. ROS is giving me a lot of trouble and the tutorials are not always so helpful. Thank you for any feedback!

EDIT: CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg message_generation)

## Declare ROS messages and services
##add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
##add_service_files(FILES AddTwoInts.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
##generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package( CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime)

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_server add_two_ints_server.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_server ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_server beginner_tutorials_gencpp)

add_executable(add_two_ints_client add_two_ints_client.cpp)
target_link_libraries(add_two_ints_client ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(add_two_ints_client beginner_tutorials_gencpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237935/creating-a-ros-msg-and-srv-tutorial-problems/) by [Starmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27266/starmit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With these kind of questions, you should indeed include your `CMakeLists.txt` so we can see whether you made any mistakes, as @ROSkinect suggests.

But in this case I *think* there is enough information in the error message you posted (I've left out some bits):

> ```
> [..] directory not found: /home/user_name/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/src/srv
> ```

```
Call Stack (most recent call first): beginner_tutorials/src/CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_service_files)
```

I believe the directory argument you give to `add_service_files(..)` is *relative to the `CMakeLists.txt` it is being called in* (but only if you don't specify an absolute path). From the error message it would seem you have your `CMakeLists.txt` in `beginner_tutorials/src`, and not in the more customary `beginner_tutorials` top-level directory.

As you can see in the error message, the build system is looking for a directory `beginner_tutorials/src/srv`, while the tutorial instructs you to create the directory `srv` directly under the `beginner_tutorials` directory.

`src/srv` != `srv`, so I'm guessing that's why CMake is complaining.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Starmit](https://answers.ros.org/users/27266/starmit/) on 2016-06-28**:
I added CMakeLists.txt to the original question. I'm looking through the files and a lot of what you said isn't present. srv is not in my src folder. I tried moving CMakeLists.txt to the beginner tutorials top-level directory and that didn't fix anything either.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-28**:
Your beginner tutorials directory should have a `CMakeLists.txt` in the top level, and there should be a subdirectory called `srv/` that contains `AddTwoInts.srv`. I.e., the fullpath would be something like `/home/user/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/srv/AddTwoInts.srv`.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-06-28**:
You can see the correct structure of your package here (if your version doesn't match, it's not correct): https://github.com/ros/catkin_tutorials/tree/master/create_package_srvclient/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-29**:\

> a lot of what you said isn't present. srv is not in my src folder

@Starmit: that could very well be the case. As I said: I took an educated guess.

Could you include the output of `tree /home/user/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials` in your original post? Use the *edit* link/button.